# VBA import multiple text files. Keeps moving data

Tags: excel, vba, text, import

I am working on a macro to import text files into a worksheet. I recorded a macro and adjusted the code slightly to suit my needs. I need to do this for multiple files so I copied and pasted the code to other macros and I am having a problem. The first iteration works great but when I run the second one it moves the original data that I imported over several columns to the right starting in column AA and posts the next batch of data in column A where it should be but much further down in line with the last row of data from the first batch. Can anyone suggest why this is not just adding the new data below the last row from the previous iteration? Here is my code. 
(edited) - I changed the code pasted to the second iteration that shows the last row line as opposed to the first row being hard coded.

```
Sub Upload2()
row = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Dump").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
filepath = Worksheets("Upload").Cells(5, "H")
Worksheets("Data Dump").Activate
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" + filepath, Destination:=Cells(row, "A"))
    '.CommandType = 0
    .Name = "bench test"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 65001
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

Dim Cn As Variant

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each Cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    Cn.Delete
Next Cn
For Each Cn In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
    Cn.Delete
Next Cn

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Thanks
Max

Comment: See revised answer following posting of the code giving the error...

Comment: Have you tried the answer provided?

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:*** *Following posting of the code giving the error.*

The code is doing that because it imports the next text file starting at the last line of the previous file.

Replace this line:

```
row = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Dump").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
```

with this

```
row = 2 + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Dump").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
```

Suggest to add `2` lines in order to leave *one blank line between each of the text files* for easy identification and integrity check afterwards.

Comment: Thanks EEM. I copied the first iteration of this macro to post here but the subsequent iterations all have the line you suggested already. Sorru I should have posted one of those instead of the first one since it actually works correctly. Thanks for the input just the same though.

Comment: Not smart at all posting the piece that works... And still, have not posted the piece with problems as yet...

Comment: Sorry it is on my other computer. I will post it later when I have a chance.

Answer (score -1):

In newer versions of excel , once text to columns has been used , the entire sheet is setup to do that from column choosen.

On subsequent loops skip the text to columns section and just paste the file into col A

Or import all files first and then do the. Text to columns

Comment: Thanks very much Steven. I will try that approach. So if I skip the text to columns that would include everything from this line:  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" + filepath, Destination:=Cells(row, "A")) down to this line correct?     .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With Thanks for the help, Max